# Merge data from XML-files with XSLT in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I trying to combine data from one XML-file and one Excel XML-file with XSLT. I can't get it to work and wonder if I can do it like this? I have not managed to get any output and could really use some help.

```
<?php

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("file1.xsl");
$inputdom = new DomDocument();
$inputdom->load("file1.xml");

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl = $proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$proc->setParameter(null, "", "");

$newdom = $proc->transformToDoc($inputdom);
print $newdom-> saveXML();
```

.xsl

How to use the ss prefix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xml')">
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="/Test">
    <Test>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$file2/Test/*" />
    </Test>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to say for sure without seeing the XML files in the question, but if the second file is Excel XML, then the root element will be **Workbook** but your XSLT is looking for a root of **Test**.

Try replacing this line....

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$file2/Test/*" />
```

With this line

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$file2/*" />
```

If you wanted to explicit refer to an element in your second file, using the **ss** namespace, you would do something like this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$file2/ss:Workbook" />
```